# Why does my API data show up as undefined when using a v-if in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

TEMPLATE

```
<template>
<div class="profile-container">
    <div class="theme-container">
      <img class="theme" src="#" alt="PH">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-pic-container">
      <img class="profile-pic" :src="responseData.profile_pic" alt="PH">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-container">
      <div class="follow-message-button-container">
        <button class="direct-message-button btn"><svg><use href="#chat-icon"></use></svg></button>
        <Follow v-if="responseData.followers.includes($store.state.userId)"></Follow>
      </div>
      <h3 class="profile-username">@{{responseData.username}}</h3>
      <p class="profile-bio">{{responseData.bio}}</p>
      <div class="follower-following-count">
        <a href="#" class="follower-count">Followers: {{responseData.followers.length}}</a>
        <a href="#" class="following-count">Following: {{responseData.following.length}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`responseData.followers.length` works correctly but `responseData.followers.includes($store.state.userId)` does not. It gives me an error saying:

> Cannot read property includes of undefined

SCRIPT

```
<script>
import Follow from "@/components/Follow";
import getAPICall from "@/mixins/getAPICall";
import getSecondAPICall from "@/mixins/getSecondAPICall";
import Post from "@/components/Post";

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  components: {Post, Follow},
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      responseData: {},
      responseData2: {},
      APIUrl: `api/user/${this.$route.params.userId}`
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mixins: [getAPICall, getSecondAPICall],
  created() {
    this.getAPICall(this.APIUrl)
    this.getSecondAPICall(`api/user-post-list/${this.$route.params.userId}`)
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what my axios api call looks like

MIXINS

```
import {getAPI} from "@/axios.api";
import store from "@/store";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            getAPICall(APIUrl) {
                getAPI.get(APIUrl, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`}}
                ).then(response => {
                    this.responseData = response.data
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    store.dispatch('useRefreshToken'
                    ).then(_ => {
                        console.log(_)
                        getAPI.get(APIUrl, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`}}
                        ).then(response => {
                            this.responseData = response.data
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I console log responseData in the created() hook I get an empty proxy.

When I console log it in the mounted hook I get a proxy object with the correct data but if I try to call my API mixins from the mounted hook I still get the same error as before and the rest of my page breaks.

Console logging responseData in the browser returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make sure that you have `responseData` . As vue is first creating the template it is looking for properties in `reponseData`.  And in this case it is not finding the properties. I faced such problems few times. The page is rendered before the api is returing data. Declare `responseData: null` and check

```
<div class="profile-container" v-if=" responseData !== null">
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is here,

**responseData.followers** is not take place immediately when render. because api call response will take time. so replace that line like this way

```
  <Follow 
    v-if="responseData.followers && responseData.followers.includes($store.state.userId)">
    </Follow>
```

and may be you should call those api synchronously, but it is depending on your requirement. if there is any dependency between those two api then should call synchronously but any other case it is ok.

```
//asynchronous operation

    created() {
        this.getAPICall(this.APIUrl)
        this.getSecondAPICall(`api/user-post-list/${this.$route.params.userId}`)
      }

//synchronous operation
async created() {
   await this.getAPICall(this.APIUrl)
   await this.getSecondAPICall(`api/user-post-list/${this.$route.params.userId}`)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is little change required in your code like `followers: []` has set in your `data()` return

```
data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      responseData: {followers: []},
      responseData2: {},
      APIUrl: `api/user/${this.$route.params.userId}`
    }
  },
```